# How mapping using HOKUYO LIDAR (URG-04LX) and hector_slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, rviz, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I've been working on ROS Fuerte for a month in order
create a map using only LIDAR (URG/04LX) no odometer with hector slam, without much success, until the moment all I can do is watch the hokuyo_node data displayed in rviz, but when I throw hokuyo_node + hector_slam (tutorial.launch) not any map is created, not to do I'm desperate, someone has to launch file I need is?

additional information
I'm using a virtual machine
Hokuyo connected by usb

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64644/how-mapping-using-hokuyo-lidar-(urg-04lx)-and-hector_slam?/) by [MAXIMOS](https://answers.ros.org/users/5101/maximos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-10**:
You must also have an IMU for hector_slam.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-06-10**:
I think this is not correct, @TJump. I think it can enhance the results, but it is not a requirement. At least I'm using HectorSlam without IMU.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-06-10**:
Yes, as long as you take care to keep your LIDAR level (i.e. no roll/pitch motion), things should also work without an IMU (and just providing a fixed transform between laser and base_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I was able to map using hector slam (tutorial.launch) and the Hokuyo URG-04LX

apparently the problem was this first of all had to modify the settings specified hector_mapping.launch setting for your robot. After that what you have to do is modify the file tutorial.launch use_sim_time setting the parameter to false, apparently when using .bag files. hector_slam works well by setting the parameter to true, but with some LIDAR use this parameter must be false.

and finally launch so are my files, put them in a package called "uprobotics"

slam.launch

---

```
<launch>

<param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>ros

<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.vcg"/>

<include file="$(find uprobotics)/launch/hector_mapping.launch"/>

<include file="$(find uprobotics)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
<arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/> 
</include>

</launch>
```

hector_mapping.launch

```
<launch>

<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping"    output="screen">

<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.025"/>
<param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value="7.5" />

<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
</node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster"      args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />  

</launch>
```

geotiff_mapper.launch

in this file was modified only thing is the path where you save the geotiff generated in this case / home / viki / Desktop / maps

---

```
<launch>
<arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" default="/base_link"/>
<arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
<arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>

<node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
<param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
<param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
<param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
<param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
</node>


<node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
<remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
<param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="/home/viki/Desktop/maps" />
<param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="uprobotics" />
<param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="0" />
<param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
<param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
</node>

</launch>
```

and is run as follows

$ roscore

$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0

$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node

$ uprobotics slam.launch

and so far seems to work wonders

I hope this is helpful for someone.

notes:

I'm using ros fuerte

I am running ros in a virtual machine with virtualbox

I'm using the Hokuyo URG-04LX for usb

---

Originally posted by [MAXIMOS](https://answers.ros.org/users/5101/maximos/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cássio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5385/c%C3%A1ssio/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thanks, you have solved my issue!

**Comment by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on 2014-04-03**:
Hi, How can I use these launch file? :( I made a package and create these launch file in launch directory but the uprobotic command doesn't work. I am new in ros and I don't know how can I use these. Please help me.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-04-18**:
I think you have to read tutorials to understand ros...
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

**Comment by [Chaiyakit](https://answers.ros.org/users/24164/chaiyakit/) on 2015-10-05**:
I use same code and parameter. But, I have problem mapping is distort and show message "searchDir angle change too large" This post >> http://answers.ros.org/question/218627/how-to-fix-problem-searchdir-angle-change-too-large/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a problem it is advisable that you supply as much information as possible (i.e. terminal Debug output etc) so people can get a better picture of what's going on. I suspect that you publish no transform between your LIDAR and the base link of your robot. An example of doing that is given in [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/53611/hector_mapping-base_link-laser-transform-times-out-once/) (the "static_transform_publisher" part).

If you want to provide further info, please edit your original post or comment on this, but do not post it as another answer.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1